# Large discrepancy between confidence intervals for correlation coefficient using bootstrap and Fisher's Z transform

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I found that the default confidence intervals provided by cor.test (Fisher's Z transform according to the help) are quite different from the nonparametric boostrap confidence intervals for the below data. Is it normal this large discrepancy? I am doing something wrong?

```
dat<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=c(2.4,2.6,3.5,7,8.1))
cor.test(dat$x,dat$y)$conf.int
bootCor<-boot(dat,function(d,i) return(cor(d[i,1],d[i,2])),R=1000)
quantile(bootCor$t,c(.025,.975),na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Your sample is so small that the probability to have only two unique value pairs in the bootstrap resamples (resulting in $r_i=1$) is pretty high. Sometimes there is even only one unique value pair (indicated by the warnings that `the standard deviation is zero`). I wouldn't recommend bootstrapping pearson r with a sample size of only 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sample size of 5! Bootstrap is really a large-sample technique, and should not be expected to work well with $n=5$.  From the comments:

Your sample is so small that the probability to have only two unique value pairs in the bootstrap resamples (resulting in $r_i=1$) is pretty high. Sometimes there is even only one unique value pair (indicated by the warnings that `the standard deviation is zero`). I wouldn't recommend bootstrapping pearson r with a sample size of only 5. – Roland